# CVOpenGLESTextureCache & CVMetalTextureCache correct usage

Tags: ios, opengl-es, avfoundation, core-video, cvpixelbuffer

There is very little documentation available on CVOpenGLESTextureCache & CVMetalTextureCache, more specifically about their correct usage. For the purpose of mapping CVPixelBuffer to OpenGLES texture, we create texture cache as follows:

```
 let err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, oglContext as CVEAGLContext, nil, &textureCache)
        if err != 0 {
            NSLog("Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate %d", err)
            success = false
            break bail
        }
```

and then we create an OpenGLES texture from a CVPixelBuffer using CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(...) API.

Metal flow is exactly same, first create CVMetalTextureCache

```
  if CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, device!, nil, &metalTextureCache) == kCVReturnSuccess {

  }
```

and then create Metal Texture from CVPixelBuffer using CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(...) API.

My questions:

1. How many CVOpenGLESTextureCache/CVMetalTextureCache objects can we create? Is there a hidden performance penalty by using multiple texture cache objects in the code? I see some codes create one global texture cache and some create multiple texture cache objects.
2. OpenGLES code uses EAGLContext to create texture cache, which means we can not reuse same CVOpenGLESTextureCache on multiple threads. However, it appears we can have just one CVMetalTextureCache which can be reused across all threads. Is that really the case?
3. I get CVPixelBuffer objected from camera which are IOSurface backed up. I am recreating OpenGLES/Metal texture multiple times for the same CVPixelBuffer in different methods, possibly using a different texture cache object, and may be on different threads. Is that the right way of doing things from performance and memory management perspective? Or should I create OpenGLES/Metal texture objects once and for all and feed the texture to multiple methods?

Comment: For 1. I think you could replace all instances of "texture cache" with "texture", so use as many textures as makes sense in your app. There might be performance benefits in grouping/atlas-ing images with similar usage patterns into one big texture. Measure it. That said, I once created hundreds of gles texture cache textures and got some slower than expected results, but that was years ago, so ... measure it.

Comment: How do we measure it exactly, because there are so many threads and render paths getting executed simultaneously and video frames coming constantly?

Comment: @DeepakSharma Did you get any better understanding about this? Any leads or material helped? I am also trying to learn more about how CVMetalTextureCache and other Core Video classes and functions work like CVPixelBufferPool etc.

Comment: @RohanSanap Not entirely. I posted more questions on it but it remains a mystery